# in a javascript object literal, how to reference a function that has the same level or upper level?

Tags: javascript, json, object

as the following code, my question is: 
in testFunction, how can i call function remove?
in remove how can i call testFunction?
in remove, how can i call add?

great thanks

```
var stringhelper={
testFunction:function(){},

//deal with text such as:
//"alignleft red bold header2"
classValue:{
    //test whether classValue has className in it
    has:function(classValue,className){
        var regex=new RegExp("(^|\\s+)"+className+"(\\s+|$)");
        return regex.test(classValue);
    },

    remove:function(classValue,className){
        return classValue.replace(className,"").replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    },

    add:function(classValue,className){
        if(/^\s+$/.test(classValue)){
            return className;
        }

        if(!this.has(classValue,className)){
            return classValue+" "+className;    
        }

    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `remove()` from `testFunction()` you can do:

```
this.classValue.remove();
```

To go the other way I think you'd have to use

```
stringhelper.testFunction();
```

as you don't have a variable containing the function or the parent `this` object (which you could use in a closure).

Comment: Why not `stringhelper.classValue.remove()`? This way, aliasing of functions won't mess up `this` reference.